# Python Sympy angle of a complex number?

Tags: python, math, sympy, complex-numbers

What is the sympy function to obtain the angle of a complex number?

In numpy, I can do:

```
numpy.angle(complexnumber)
```

In sympy, I want to just be able to take the angle of an expression:

```
sympy.givemeangle(sympyexpression_whichevaluatestoacomplexnumber)
```

I suppose I could implement my own logic to check which quadrant the number is in, and then deal with inverse tan function depending on the coord... but I would really like to just not know what quadrant an expression ends up being in, and be able to think of the expression's angle.

What should I do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it!

```
n = sympyexpression_whichevaluatestoacomplexnumber
expressionangle = sympy.arg( n )
```

Also a slight modification of `Tom's` suggestion works:

```
expressionangle2 = sympy.log( n ).as_real_imag()[1]
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: If you want a one-liner, you can also do this in one line using `log`, and grabbing the complex part: `complex(sympy.log( sympyexpression_whichevaluatestoacomplexnumber )).imag`  But `atan2` is probably more familiar to most people.